# Cocos 2d-x html5 ios call native obj-c methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, html, cocos2d-iphone

I decided to build my first game on cocos2d-html5 engine. But before I start developing I've made some research and coulnd't find any good tutorial how to communicate with 3rd party SDK via HTML5. For example I will need to integrate game center, flurry, admob, chartboost and many other stuff.

I already did several games using HTML + Phonegap, there you can create plugins which allows you to call native functions.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: then why not continue with phonegap?

Comment: I read that the game performance will be very low if it run under PhoneGap

Comment: did you try? Making decisions based on hearsay is not, well, not an informed decision.